# Run serveral daemon using python

Tags: performance, python, daemon

I noticed that serveral daemon invoked python seperately.
For example, I have both wicd and ibus daemon running on my machine. Instead of launching a single instance of python, the daemons run with two python instance at the same time in htop:

```
/usr/bin/python2 -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/monitor.py
python2 /usr/share/ibus/ui/gtk/main.py
```

Is it a waste of doing that?
If yes, how can I improve this?
If no, why avoid putting all daemons run on a single python instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a waste. It is normal for **separate programs** to be running in **separate processes**, so that they couldn't (accidentally or intentionally) modify each other's state. Separate processes also mean that if one program crashes, all others are left unaffected.